# AngularJS forEaach on html element

Tags: angularjs

How can i loop html element in angularJS?

html:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>AngularJS</li>
    <li>jQuery</li>
    <li>Backbone</li>
    <li>ExtJS</li>
</ul>
```

In jQuery:

```
var array = [];
$('ul#list li').each(function(index,value){
     array.push($(value).text());
});
```

How can i get the same result in angularJS?

Comment: Perhaps `ng-repeat` could be of use http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul ng-init="list = ['AngularJS','jQuery',Backbone','ExtJS']" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: HTML already exists from that ul#list i need to get all the li value in array.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you would tackle this problem the other way around.
Define your array in your controller:

```
$scope.array = ['AngularJS', 'JQuery', 'Backbone', 'ExtJS'];
```

and in your html use the ng-repeat directive:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in array">{{a}}</li>
</ul>
```

and now you can access the array in JS via `$scope.array`

Comment: I want to perform in reverse from the html i needs to get the array. Is tat possible?